# Making a dynamically named iframe editable

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

I am trying to write a function that will make a certain iFrame editable.  I'm not sure where I am going wrong and would be very grateful for any assistance.

I have posted a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/edmozley/wt0pLxy0/2/

```
    <html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%">
          <div id="div1" style="position:relative;border:1px solid black;">Div 1<br>
            <iframe name="div1_msg" id="div1_msg" style="border:3px solid green"></iframe>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td width="50%">
          <div id="div2" style="position:relative;border:1px solid black;">Div 2<br>
            <iframe name="div2_msg" id="div2_msg" style="border:3px solid red"></iframe>
          </div>
        </td>
    </table>

    <input type="button" value="Div 1 Editable" onclick="makeEditable('div1');">
    <input type="button" value="Div 2 Editable" onclick="makeEditable('div2');">

  </body>

  <script>
    function makeEditable(divName)
    {
    divName+'_msg'.document.designMode = 'On';
    }
  </script>
<html>
```

Thanks very much

Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`divName+'_msg'.document.designMode` is invalid javascript, you can't concatenate strings and use them in dot notation.

You'd that like so, with bracket notation, accessing the frame with a given name etc.

```
function makeEditable(divName) {
    window[divName + '_msg'].document.designMode = 'On';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wt0pLxy0/3/)

Comment: Spot on, but you're accessing the frame with a given *ID*, rather than name. even though they are are the same in this instance

Comment: @RGraham - I actually thought I did `window.frames[name]`, but see now that I forgot the `frames` part ! It doesn't really matter, it still works, and even removing the ID from the element should work as it falls back to the name.